# Saving Style as SLD in QGIS but after reloading unit changes from map units to pixel?

Tags: qgis, sld, pixel, outline, map-unit

I have a style I am saving in QGIS (2.18) as an SLD.
After reloading the Style onto the layer the ouline width changes to pixels instead of map units.

I even checked the .sld in notepad and the uom-Tag is there.
(uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">)

Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. You should check the [issue tracker](https://issues.qgis.org) to see if it has been resolved for more recent versions of QGIS. If it hasn't been reported, please report it.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently (QGIS 3.24.3) a bug in QGIS, bug report on the QGIS issue tracker:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/48848

Starting with QGIS 3.26.0, uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre" is decoded to 'Meters at Scale:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/48989